# Apply formulas to specific cells

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm creating an Excel file using vb.NET but I have the following problem/situation:

> I want to add a formula to my cells on specific row and on specific starting position, for example: from F5 to Z5. The main problem is that I need to do two formulas the first one ONLY on the first cell (F5 for example) and from F5 to Z5 another formula. The other problem is for example, I have data from A1 to Z5 then I insert a blank row and then I have data from A7 to Z7.

At the moment I have a code which allows me to move from cell F5 to Z5 one cell per one cell but only insert data (formula) on F5 and G5 because I don't know how to handle the range without letters. This is an example of my code:

```
'' LastLetter is equal to the index o Z Column (I always know which is the last column letter.)
For workingOnCell As Integer = 7 To lastCellLetter Step 1
    If itsFirtsCell = 1 Then
        Dim select As Excel.Range = CType(SW.Cells(5, workingOnCell), Excel.Range)
        '' Formula only for first cell
        select.Value = "=F2+F3+F4"
        itsFirtsCell = 0
    Else
        Dim select As Excel.Range = CType(SW.Cells(5, workingOnCell), Excel.Range)
        '' Formula for all the rest of cells
        '' Problem starts here because formula for second cell it's ok but for the third cell should be =G5-H2-H3-H4 and here is where I don't know how to handle cell letters
        select.Value = "=F5-G2-G3-G4"
    End If
Next
```

Other problem with above code is that if I have data on A7:Z7 range I should do the same thing but my code only going to work with F5:Z5.

How can I make my code works as expected or how can I solved it?

Comment: Can't you just use R1C1 references?

Comment: @Cominterm Mmm... honestly I didn’t know about that references style but look great to solve my problem I’m going to search it but you could give me an example as an answer